# ListView ItemClickListener works when double clicked ,not responding for single click

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

following code is for itemclick listener

```
ListView_proddetails.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("clicked--");
        SalesReturnDetails returnDetails = (SalesReturnDetails) parent
                                        .getAdapter().getItem(position);
        ArrayList<SalesReturnDetails> arrData = new ArrayList<SalesReturnDetails>();
        arrData.add(returnDetails);
        Intent intent = new Intent(SalesReturnCreation.this, SalesReturnProductDetails.class);
        try {
            intent.putExtra("itemdata", ObjectConversion.serialize(arrData));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        intent.putExtra("from", "MainList");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

following is list_item_row.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeitem"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/remove_button_shape"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="Remove"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_details_child"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_details_titlename"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#0C090A"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_details_qty_titlename"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#848482"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_details_total_text"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#848482"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_details_remove_child"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/removeitem"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_details_remove_titlename"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#0C090A"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_details_qty_remove_titlename"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#848482"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and part of xml file where list view have been used,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearProductDetails"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearIssue"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Product_List_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Product List"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"   />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_Product_List_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/txt_bg"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="add"
        android:textColor="#357EC7"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/id_linesp2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Product_List_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@color/light_grey" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/Product_List_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/id_linesp2"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried following options but no use

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"    and

android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

may be i dont know where to supply them exactly,,

friends work out with above code and guide me to make listview responding to single click,

this is how list view looks after single click no response,[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as your list row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/removeitem"
        android:layout_width="82dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/remove_button_shape"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="Remove"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_details_child"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_details_titlename"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#0C090A"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_details_qty_titlename"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#848482"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_details_total_text"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#848482"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_details_remove_child"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/removeitem"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_details_remove_titlename"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#0C090A"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_details_qty_remove_titlename"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#848482"
            android:textSize="14dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not working @suitianshi whenever i click listview it just changes color but clickevent not fired but when double clicked it works